# Compile web application without web.config

Tags: asp.net

When I am running new asp.net application it asks for add web.config file. So Can we compile asp.net application without web.config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Can an ASP.NET web app run without web.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071750/can-an-asp-net-web-app-run-without-web-config)

Comment: You need to understand the difference between "compile" and "run". Visual Studio will happily compile any code that doesn't have errors. However, running is totally different.

Comment: Dear friend I knew about your suggestion and thanks for your kind suggestion but my friend question remain same. Visual studio shows web.config file missing error and ask for add web.config. So my question is still same can we avoid those error to add web.config file if not exist at the time of compilation.